# What does L == 2 mean in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, syntax

```
    BW = logical([1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
                  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
                  1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0
                  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
                  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
                  1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0
                  1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0
                  1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]);
    L = bwlabel(BW,4);
    [r,c] = find(L == 2);
```

How can a matrix been compared with scalar?

Comment: Welcome to Matlab, where comparing to scalar is easier.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe a visual example might help.

```
>> b=[1 2 3;2 3 1;3 1 2]

b =

     1     2     3
     2     3     1
     3     1     2



>> b==2

ans =

     0     1     0
     1     0     0
     0     0     1



>> b==3

ans =

     0     0     1
     0     1     0
     1     0     0
```

A logical-class matrix of the same size as the matrix being compared is returned.

```
>> find(ans)

ans =

     2
     4
     9
```

`find` then returns the linear address of the non-zero elements.

Answer (score 4):

Afair comparing a matrix with an scalar results in element-wise comparison. I.e. each element of the matrix is compared with the scalar. The result is a matrix with 1 in all positions for which the comparison returned true and 0 in all other positions.

`find` on the other hand returns all indices for which the argument is non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

"How can a matrix been compared with scalar?": try `doc eq` at the matlab prompt and it says:

> A == B compares each element ... for
>   equality ... Each input of the
>   expression can be an array or a scalar
>   value.
>
> If one input is scalar and the other a
>   nonscalar array, then the scalar input
>   is treated as if it were an array
>   having the same dimensions as the
>   nonscalar input array. In other words,
>   if input A is the number 100, and B is
>   a 3-by-5 matrix, then A is treated as
>   if it were a 3-by-5 matrix of
>   elements, each set to 100. MATLAB
>   returns an array of the same
>   dimensions as the nonscalar input
>   array.

Answer (score 1):

The `find(L==2)` will return all the rows and columns of  elements that are equal to 2.

So, if you get `[r]=[1 2 3 5 6]` and `[c]=[1 2 3 5 6]`, that means that the rows and columns of the elements that are equal to 2 is `{1,1}`, `{2,2}`, `{3,3}` and so on.

The official matlab explanation [is here](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/find.html). You can also google the term "[matlab find](http://www.google.com.my/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=find+matlab)"

Comment: @user198729, I think I explain the answer in detail?

Comment: It's called "scalar expansion".

Answer (score 1):

See the [`bwlabel`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) function, it will be useful for you.

Example:

Label components using 4-connected objects. Notice objects 2 and 3; with 8-connected labeling, `bwlabel` would consider these a single object rather than two separate objects.

```
BW = logical ([1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0  
               1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
               1     1     1     0     1     1     0     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
               1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0]);

L = bwlabel(BW,4)

L =

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
     1     1     1     0     2     2     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     3     3     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0

[r, c] = find(L==2);
rc = [r c]

rc =

     2     5
     3     5
     2     6
     3     6
```

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation:

Say,

```
A = [1 2 3 
     4 5 6
     7 8 9]
```

then when you say:

```
A == 5;
```

what MATLAB sees (the actual implementation is for more different than this, but the logic stays the same):

```
A == B*5;
```

where,

```
B = [1 1 1
     1 1 1
     1 1 1];
```

You can extend this for an arbitrary A matrix.

Same for addition.